# 301 htaccess redirect not working (for a single page)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Putting this at the top of my htaccess file doesn't do anything:

```
Redirect 301 /taxonomy/term/6%207%208%209 http://mysite.com/taxonomy/term/all
```

Neither does this:

```
Redirect 301 http://mysite.com/taxonomy/term/6%207%208%209 http://mysite.com/taxonomy/term/all
```

Im using a CMS that uses its own htaccess file so could it be my rule are being overridden? I thought that putting the code at the top of the file would solve this? Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to redirect `/taxonomy/term/6 7 8 9`?

Comment: Yes, im trying to redirect from that url. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escapes get decoded before going through mod_alias, so the `%20`'s get turned back into spaces. You need to put them in quotes:

```
Redirect 301 "/taxonomy/term/6 7 8 9" http://mysite.com/taxonomy/term/all
```